How to fill three areas inside a closed curve with different colors?
The closed oriented curve c intersects itself at two points, creating three different components (areas) A_1, A_2, A_3. How can we fill with different color each of these three components, maintaining simultaneously the smoothness of the curve?
A MWE is given below.

    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}


%arrows along curve
\tikzset{
    set arrow inside/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/arrow inside}{#1}},
    set arrow inside={end/.initial=>, opt/.initial=},
    /pgf/decoration/Mark/.style={
        mark/.expanded=at position #1 with
        {
            \noexpand\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/opt}]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arrow inside/end}}
        }
    },
    arrow inside/.style 2 args={
        set arrow inside={#1},
        postaction={
            decorate,decoration={
                markings,Mark/.list={#2}
            }
        }
    },
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,>=stealth]
    \draw [line width=1.2pt, arrow inside={end=stealth,opt={scale=1.25}}{0.05, 0.2, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4,0.52,0.65, 0.8,0.95}] plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2.5,-3) (0.5,3.5) (3.,3) (4.5,3) (7,-3)  (3,-2.5) (1.5,2) (-0.3,1)  (0.4,0) (0,-2) (3,0.5) (4.8,-1)(4,-2.5)};
    \begin{Large}
        \draw[color=black] (5.5,2.5) node {$c$};
        \draw[color=blue] (0.9,0.9) node {$A_1$};
        \draw[color=red] (3.5,-1) node {$A_2$};
        \draw[color=green] (3,1.7) node {$A_3$};    
    \end{Large}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[save path=\mypath] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2.5,-3) (0.5,3.5) (3.,3) (4.5,3) (7,-3) (3,-2.5) (1.5,2) (-0.3,1) (0.4,0) (0,-2) (3,0.5) (4.8,-1) (4,-2.5)};
\fill[blue!50] (-1,-2.5) -- (-0.5,1.5) -- (2,2.8) -- (3,-1) -- cycle;
\fill[red!50, use path=\mypath]; 
\fill[green!50, even odd rule, use path=\mypath];
\draw[ultra thick, use path=\mypath]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you hpekristiansen! Another example based on the hpekristiansen's answer.

\documentclass[tikz, border=0.0cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\path[save path=\mypath] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(4.0,-2.5) (5,-1.0) (4.0,0.5) (1,-2) (-0.5,1.0) (2.8,2) (3.0,-2.5) (7,-3) (6,4) (3,3.5)  (-2,5) (-3.0,1) (1.5,-0.4) (-0.5,3)  (-3.5,-3)};
\fill[blue!40] (-1,-1.5) -- (1,2.8) -- (4.5,2.) -- (2,-2.5) -- cycle;
\fill[red!40, use path=\mypath]; 
\fill[green!40, even odd rule, use path=\mypath];
\draw[line width=1.2pt, use path=\mypath]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


So the trick is just to draw the areas on top of each other?

@PaŭloEbermann Not only! The command "even odd rule" it's also crucial.
